# Apache 2.4.10 giving 403 Forbidden issue on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: permissions, apache2.4

I am setting up PHP environment. Now when I have started to add my sites from windows/xampp backup *(mentioning so just in case any path related issue)*

I have created new project (netbeans) and created test inedx.php and that I am able to access. However, When I am trying to access the site it is giving `403 Forbidden` message for the site.

I am trying to resolve this since last night

Comment: on windows ? or on ubuntu ?

Comment: I am having problem on Ubuntu. I am switching completely on Ubuntu from Windows

Comment: I have changed permission again to 775 and now able to access the root of the site. But when I am trying access any page, it is giving 404 Not Found error. So I believe it is now mod rewrite issue. I have already enabled it. So do I need to write any code for mod rewrite?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Okay so after hitting hammer in my head, I found working properly. However I am not so sure if I have done correctly or there is any better approach to make it works.

What I have done first is,
Change permission for entire `/var/www` again. I just wonder, why I have to reset it after pasting the site, I have done that before.

```
sudo chmod -R 775 /var/www
```

You may like to change group or owner etc..(also let me know if any good way to assign owner or group)

Than, I have added rewrite rule as below in..

```
sudo gedit /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```

Add below to `000-default.conf`

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
  AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

I checked and now everything is working fine.

Please, correct me or guide me if there is any better approach. I have just search here in some answers and apply simple logic to fix it. I am newbie and not good in all these.

Answer (score 10):

Try this solution

https://askubuntu.com/a/601722/392041

basically just replace

```
Order allow,deny
allow from all
```

with

```
Require all granted
```

You could find the reason for this here in this link http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html

> If you wish to restrict access to portions of your site based on the host address of your visitors, this is most easily done using **mod_authz_host**.
>
> The **Require** provides a variety of different ways to allow or deny access to resources. In conjunction with the **RequireAll**, **RequireAny**, and **RequireNone** directives, these requirements may be combined in arbitrarily complex ways, to enforce whatever your access policy happens to be.
>
> The **Allow**, **Deny**, and **Order** directives, provided by **mod_access_compat**, are deprecated and will go away in a future version. You should avoid using them, and avoid outdated tutorials recommending their use.