# LAMP 403 forbidden access on custom folder

Tags: permissions, apache2, lamp

I know it is a common problem, and it is mainly a matter of permissions to the user `www-data`, but following [this](https://docs.joomla.org/Configuring_a_LAMPP_server_for_PHP_development/Linux_desktop) guide I got the classic error:

```
403 forbidden 
You don't have permission to access /web on this server.
```

I was not able to find a solution online, despite the huge amount of people facing the same issue. Sorry! :)

This is my `000-default.conf` file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /home/tom/Dropbox/web
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    <Directory /home/tom/Dropbox/web>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride All
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /home/tom/Dropbox/web/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog home/tom/Dropbox/web/access.log combined

 Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
 <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
     Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverride All
     Order deny,allow
     Deny from all
     Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
 </Directory>
```

and of course, the folder in which I tried to configure my local website is in `~/Dropbox/web`.

Finally, these are the current permissions

```
drwxrwxrwx   8 tom tom   4096 mars  26 09:57 Dropbox
drwxrwxrwx   3 tom tom   4096 mars  26 11:47 web
```

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This happens after you upgrade to apache 2.4.9+

basically just replace

```
Order allow,deny
allow from all
```

with

```
Require all granted
```

should fix this issue.

something like,

```
<Directory /home/tom/Dropbox/web>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride All
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Here is a note from http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html

> If you wish to restrict access to portions of your site based on the host address of your visitors, this is most easily done using **mod_authz_host**.
>
> The **Require** provides a variety of different ways to allow or deny access to resources. In conjunction with the **RequireAll**, **RequireAny**, and **RequireNone** directives, these requirements may be combined in arbitrarily complex ways, to enforce whatever your access policy happens to be.
>
> The **Allow**, **Deny**, and **Order** directives, provided by **mod_access_compat**, are deprecated and will go away in a future version. You should avoid using them, and avoid outdated tutorials recommending their use.

Comment: @Sfrow did "Require all granted" solve the issue?

Comment: 7 StackOverflow question in. This was the easiest and best to implement!