# ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED when create virtual host for wordpress website

Tags: networking, server, grub2, software-installation

I try to create virtual host on ubuntu server, but I get the message like image.

[image]

Comment: Your image doesn't appear. Could you try again? Also could you list your ubuntu version please?

Comment: did you add in the host file the name of this domain and the localhost as ip? This error is just because no DNS (starting from hosts file) have a clue on what that domain stands for. Also have you configured a virtual host for this site in apache?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WordPress Installation Failed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/941928/wordpress-installation-failed)

Answer (score 3):

First of all you must register [dpacam.live](https://www.google.bg/#q=register+dpacam.live+domain). [It is not registered yet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFlW7.png)! After that, you must connect [redirect] the domain (dpacam.live) with [to] your static IP address. You can do that through the administrative panel of your DNS provider. About next steps please check my answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/811401/forbidden-403-error-when-trying-to-access-apache-2-4-7-web-server-in-browser/811416#811416).

Edit: I remember that I have two comments related to the current question:

- https://askubuntu.com/a/824178/566421
- https://askubuntu.com/a/811416/566421