# How to add an html page in the apache2 root?

Tags: apache2, html

I've installed apache2 on ubuntu and I want to add an html page on it's root to see if it works. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default Apache2 Document Root directory on Ubuntu is: `/var/www/html`.

It is defined in the configuration file `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`. You can enable and disable this default [virtual host](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html) via these commands:

```
sudo a2ensite  000-default.conf    # which means Apache2 enable site
sudo a2dissite 000-default.conf    # which means Apache2 disable site
```

You can create [other virtual hosts](https://askubuntu.com/a/811416/566421), that points to other directories. After each of these steps or after some edits in the configuration files you must reload (or restart) Apache2:

```
sudo systemctl reload apache2.service
sudo systemctl restart apache2.service
```

By default, the directory `/var/www/html` is owned by *root*. This means when you want to edit a file in this directory you have to use `sudo` command.

For example. There is a file that contains the default welcome page. This file is called `/var/www/html/index.php`. To edit it, open a terminal window (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and use this command:

```
sudo -i gedit /var/www/html/index.html
```

It is not good practice, but for testing purposes (while using the web server only locally) you can change the owner of this directory and files in it. Use this command:

```
sudo chown -R $USER /var/www/html/
```

After that you will be able to edit and create files there, with your current user (try the command `echo $USER`).

About the permissions of this folder, please read this topic: **[How to avoid using sudo when working in /var/www?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46331/how-to-avoid-using-sudo-when-working-in-var-www)**

Comment: I've tried to modify it but it can't be modified

Comment: What you mean "it can't be modified"? Do you try to use `sudo` when you copy or create files?

Comment: can you write me the full command that I should write?

Comment: Sure, I need a moment.

Comment: I tried to edit it using gedit but I can't save it

Comment: @Matei I've updated my answer. Please, let me know if it works :)