# How to search for host in apache server?

Tags: apache2, localhost, websites

I am trying to test locally whether my virtual host is working. When i type the ServerName in the browser instead of requesting the web page from apache, chromium goes and searches the internet for websites corresponding to my virtual host. How do I make sure that what I type in the browser is requested from my apache and not from the internet?

Comment: 1st use `http://localhost` instead of just `localhost`. 2nd If you have some virtual hosts named in different way, for example `localhost2`, `elio` etc. you must bound them with an IP address through `/etc/hosts`. Please check this answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/811416/566421

Answer (score 3):

For Google Chrome/Chromium, this is essentially [a declined feature-request](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=81226). What the browser does in this case is:

> The designed way Chrome is intended to work in this case is that when
>   a user inputs something that is a potential intranet hostname, Chrome
>   does a background HTTP HEAD request to that hostname, and if it gets a
>   valid reply, it displays an infobar atop the search result page,
>   asking "Did you mean to go to `http://<hostname>/`?"  If a user clicks
>   that link, not only does it navigate to this hostname now, it also
>   remembers that hostname in the future to avoid searching again. 
>   Similarly, doing any other successful typed navigation to that host
>   (e.g. "hostname/" as suggested in (2)) will also cause Chrome to never
>   search for that host again.

The only way to go to the page directly on the *first* attempt is to disable the search.

Or use workarounds:

- Type `http://foo` or `foo/` or `foo:80`, etc.
- Switch to Firefox, which, according to the comments in that feature request, has the desired behaviour.
- Use a hostname with a `.` in it: `foo.bar`