# Make URL point to local folder

Tags: networking, redirect

I have a URL to be mapped, on my Ubuntu 16.04 machine, to a local folder.

E.g. I need `https://domainxxx.xxx` to point to `/home/user/folder`.

My specific need is to include `domainxxx.xxx/file.js` not as the real 'file.js' on the remote server, but as `/home/user/folder/file.js` which is on my machine.

I've read this is not possible with an entry in `/etc/hosts`. How can I do this?

Comment: By "mapped", do you mean that visiting https://domainxxx.xxx should have the same effect as visiting file:///home/user/folder?

Comment: My specific need is to include https://domainxxx.xxx/file.js not as the real 'file.js' on the remote server, but as /home/user/folder/file.js which is on my machine

Comment: That piece of information should have been in the question from the beginning. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Option 1: Using `file://` links**

You can point your browser to any folder on your computer using

```
file:///path/to/folder
```

A list of files should show up, similar to a File Browser. Web Browsers can also parse *.html files*, show *images*, play some *video* formats, open *text* and *xml* files from your local machine. Just point your browser to `file:///path/to/file.ext`.

---

**Option 2: Running an HTTP-Server**

If you need to parse files other than .html (e.g. `php` files) or need to access them from another computer, you need to run an *http server* like `apache`, `nginx` or Python [`SimpleHTTPServer`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html) on your local machine. Then you can use `http://` and if configured also `https://` URLs.

[Here is a nice list of Instant HTTP Server options.](https://gist.github.com/willurd/5720255)

---

**Example:**
Start an Instant http-Server using Python and **SimpleHTTPServer**

Python 2.x:

```
cd /home/user/folder && python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8082
```

Python 3.x:

```
cd /home/user/folder && python3 -m http.server 8082
```

Then open your preferred browser: http://localhost:8082/

## UPDATE:

After you added your *specific need* in the comments, I would recommend reading [this page](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Links_to_local_pages_do_not_work) why **local links inside http pages are not allowed**. Included is also a workaround (overriding the security policy using NoScript).

> For security purposes, Mozilla applications block links to local files (and directories) from remote files. This includes linking to files on your hard drive, on mapped network drives, and accessible via Uniform Naming Convention (UNC) paths. This prevents a number of unpleasant possibilities

I see three options:

- Use an (Instant) HTTP Server, then you can include `http://localhost:8082/file.js` directly.
- Overrde Firefox security policy and use a `file://` link (I would not do it when other options exist)
- Let the Server access the file via http, smb or ssh connection to serve it directly (if you're behind a router or firewall, you need to take care of port forwarding). This is quite complicated to achieve, but  is the only option that enables access from other machines (only while your computer is online).

---

Note: For better answers, **always** write the question **as specific as possible** from the beginning.

Comment: Another good option is to use the `serve` package from npm. `sudo npm install -g serve` to install. `serve /some/dir/here` to serve. I'm sure there are a ton of others too.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Apache Server your default root directory will probably be `/var/www/html` and the Apache server will look at a file or a folder named `index` like `index.html` or `index.php` to access immediately. What you need to do is:

- Go to the folder you want to be pointed to (`/home/user/folder` in your example) right click on the folder and click 'Make Link' (or whatever is the CLI alternative).
- Now that the link file is created, rename it to be 'index' an then move it to your Apache root folder `/var/www/html`.
- Last important step is to make sure that Apache has the proper permissions to access the files needed (i.e the link we created and named `index` and the `/home/user/folder` directory and the files needed to be accessed within that directory).

Answer (score 1):

First you need to install LAMP stack or just web server as: [Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/), [Lighttpd](https://www.lighttpd.net/) or [Nginx](https://nginx.org/). Then you must configure your web server and enable [HTTPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS), if you really need **s**ecure connection, not just [**HTTP**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol).

---

Here you are few HOW-TOs about Apache2:

- How-to [install LAMP](https://askubuntu.com/q/34/566421), see also [the official documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP).
- How-to [configure Apache2 Virtual Hosts](https://askubuntu.com/a/811416/566421).
- How-to [open port 80/443 (HTTP/HTTPS) into the firewall](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/firewall.html).
- How-to [enable a free certificate from Let's Encrypt](https://askubuntu.com/a/900433/566421).
- How-to [increase your web server's security](https://askubuntu.com/a/922144/566421).

Answer (score 0):

LAMP (Linux Apache MySQL and PHP) is the best way as it runs a server on your local machine. 
I wrote a how to install and set up on my website [how to install LAMP on Ubuntu](https://iancroasdell.wordpress.com/installing-lamp-on-ubuntu/)