# "This site can't be reached" when using virtual host

Tags: server, apache2

I'm trying to set up Apache2 server. Installation and configuration seemed to go well, but when I try to go to my custom web URL I get "This site can't be reached" error. I've tried setting config file up through this answer - [Forbidden 403 error when trying to access Apache 2.4.7 web server in browser](https://askubuntu.com/questions/811401/forbidden-403-error-when-trying-to-access-apache-2-4-7-web-server-in-browser#answer-811416) .

My hosts file looks like this:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1       justtestingthis
127.0.1.1   Hacker

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
...
```

My `apache2/sites-available/http.justtestingthis.conf` file looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    ServerName justtestingthis.com
    ServerAlias www.justtestingthis.com

    DocumentRoot /home/donatas/Desktop/Projects/justtestingthis/dist/src
    DirectoryIndex index.php

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <Directory /home/donatas/Desktop/Projects/justtestingthis/dist/src>
        # Allow .htaccess 
        AllowOverride All
        Allow from All
    </Directory> 
</VirtualHost>
```

I've also created a link of this file in `apache2/sites-enabled` using `sudo a2ensite http.justtestingthis.conf`.

When I'm accessing the website by just typing in http://localhost my website is being found sucessfully, but when I'm trying to access it through justtestingthis.com or www.justtestingthis.com I'm getting the "This site can't be reached error"...

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The reason why your browser cannot open the `justtestingthis.com` page is that there is no alias pointing to where it is supposed to go.  You have in your `/etc/hosts` file only `127.0.0.1 justtestingthis`, where that is just the name.  The browser has no idea where the name with `.com` is since it is not specified.

To fix this, change the line in your `/etc/hosts` to:

```
127.0.0.1 www.justtestingthis.com
```

This should now alias `justtestingthis.com` to the `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` in your web browser to your Apache page.  It will also open with `justtestingthis.com` without the www.