# EC2 Ubuntu: unable to access site from browser but able to access from EC2 Ubuntu terminal

Tags: dns, amazon-ec2

Below is my virtual host setup

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin ******.com
        ServerName ***.***.com
        ServerAlias www.***.***.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/***.***.com/public_html
        <Directory /var/www/***.***.com >
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Required all granted
        </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
```

When I do curl `http://***.***.com/` from  ec2 Ubuntu terminal, it is printing the `hello world html`. Working nicely.

Now When I access `http://***.***.com/` from a browser, it says `This site can’t be reached`

**NOTE:**

I have enabled my `***.***.com.conf`.

permission also given.

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /var/www/***.***.com/public_html
```

I have enabled port 80 to listen on `0.0.0.0`.
Also opened the port on security group as well.

**`netstat -nlp` output**

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -               
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           -               
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           -
```

Will you please help me figure out what I am missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["This site can't be reached" when using virtual host](https://askubuntu.com/questions/938761/this-site-cant-be-reached-when-using-virtual-host)

Comment: @galoget I have updated  as per given post,but still not working.Is there any EC2 additional setting need